# vector subscript out of range on Line 1455?

Tags: c++, vector

Going through a Udacity course right now on C++ and the following code works when compiled in their workspace but won't run when I try to put it into CLion and run it. I suspect something is wrong with the Search method because I tried to run the previous exercise (where Search was not filled out yet) on my machine and that still ran fine.

````
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::cout;
using std::ifstream;
using std::istringstream;
using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::abs;

enum class State {kEmpty, kObstacle, kClosed};


vector<State> ParseLine(string line) {
    istringstream sline(line);
    int n;
    char c;
    vector<State> row;
    while (sline >> n >> c && c == ',') {
        if (n == 0) {
            row.push_back(State::kEmpty);
        } else {
            row.push_back(State::kObstacle);
        }
    }
    return row;
}


vector<vector<State>> ReadBoardFile(string path) {
    ifstream myfile (path);
    vector<vector<State>> board{};
    if (myfile) {
        string line;
        while (getline(myfile, line)) {
            vector<State> row = ParseLine(line);
            board.push_back(row);
        }
    }
    return board;
}


// Calculate the manhattan distance
int Heuristic(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    return abs(x2 - x1) + abs(y2 - y1);
}


/**
 * Add a node to the open list and mark it as open.
 */
void AddToOpen(int x, int y, int g, int h, vector<vector<int>> &openlist, vector<vector<State>> &grid) {
    // Add node to open vector, and mark grid cell as closed.
    openlist.push_back(vector<int>{x, y, g, h});
    grid[x][y] = State::kClosed;
}


/**
 * Implementation of A* search algorithm
 */
vector<vector<State>> Search(vector<vector<State>> grid, int init[2], int goal[2]) {
    // Create the vector of open nodes.
    vector<vector<int>> open {};

    // Initialize the starting node.
    int x = init[0];
    int y = init[1];
    int g = 0;
    int h = Heuristic(x, y, goal[0],goal[1]);
    AddToOpen(x, y, g, h, open, grid);

    cout << "No path found!" << "\n";
    return std::vector<vector<State>>{};
}

string CellString(State cell) {
    switch(cell) {
        case State::kObstacle: return "⛰️   ";
        default: return "0   ";
    }
}


void PrintBoard(const vector<vector<State>> board) {
    for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].size(); j++) {
            cout << CellString(board[i][j]);
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}


int main() {
    int init[2]{0, 0};
    int goal[2]{4, 5};
    auto board = ReadBoardFile("1.board");
    auto solution = Search(board, init, goal);
    PrintBoard(solution);

}```
````

Comment: If you get that error, it should tell you where in your code it's failing. Which line specifically is it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at our [intro pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/help). What do you mean, it "won't run"? What do you expect, and what do you actually get?

Comment: What is `grid` in `AddToOpen`? Does it actually contain anything?

Comment: Make sure you actually read any data. Checking if a stream got opened is good, but it's useless if you ignore potential errors. What happens in `ReadBoardFile` when the file could not be opened? Right, nothing, it quietly ignores the error and returns an empty vector, that probably causes the out-of-bounds-access in `AddToOpen`. Maybe add some validation there as well and see what happens.

Comment: @ChrisMM It says line 1455 in the error message which is definitely way bigger than the code I have

Comment: Might be compiler you're using, normally would refer back to your code in the call stack. Mine shows the issue here: `grid[x][y] = State::kClosed;`, but that's because I don't have a file with anything, so `grid` is empty.... Yours may be as well though.

Comment: @Beta In this step of the tutorial, when I run it in the Udacity workspace it shows "No path found!". However, it doesn't allow me to run in my IDE showing the error message with the title

Comment: @ChrisMM I have another text file called 1.board which contains:  

0,1,0,0,0,0, <br> 

0,1,0,0,0,0, <br> 

0,1,0,0,0,0, <br> 

0,1,0,0,0,0, <br> 

0,0,0,0,1,0,

Comment: @churill ChrisMM It seems that was the problem. I added an else statement in ReadBoardFile that prints file was not found in the console and it's not finding the file for some reason. Weird cause I tried copy-pasting the fully completed project code from Udacity which outputs the completed grid fine in the Udacity workspace but still not finding my file in CLion IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out thanks to everyone here!

For some reason the relative path name in the ReadBoardFile call didn't work.
Resorting to absolute file path fixed the issue.